# React Image Carousel | Featured Image Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to build a custom modal off this react [carousel library](https://github.com/maxmarinich/react-alice-carousel)

Basically, I'm at the point where the modal is implemented correctly, but I can't seem to find out how to wire the `featured image` on the modal to always be the **same** like the one which is currently also being featured in the carousel.

```
const Modal = ({ modal, items, handleModalFalse, currentIndex, featured }) => {
  return (
    <div className={modal ? "modal" : "hide"} onClick={handleModalFalse}>
      {/* this only features the first image */}
      {/* <img src={featured} /> */}
      {/* shows every image on modal*/}
      {items.map((item, i) => (
        <div key={i} className="wrapper">
          <img src={item} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

These are all the handlers that power the Carousel.
I'm struggling to wire the featured image correctly (perhaps inside `componentDidMount()` ?)

```
class Gallery2 extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentIndex: 0,
    items: [
      "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png",
      "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png",
      "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/cat.png",
      "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png"
    ],
    modal: false,
    featured: undefined
  };

  // what should go here instead??
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ featured: this.state.items[0] });
  }

  slideTo = i => console.log("clicked") || this.setState({ currentIndex: i });

  onSlideChanged = e => this.setState({ currentIndex: e.item });

  slideNext = () =>
    this.setState({ currentIndex: this.state.currentIndex + 1 });

  slidePrev = () =>
    this.setState({ currentIndex: this.state.currentIndex - 1 });

  handleEnlargeClick = () => {
    this.setState({ modal: true });
  };

  handleModalFalse = () => {
    this.setState({ modal: false });
  };

render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h3>React Alice Carousel</h3>
        {/* MODAL */}
        <Modal
          modal={this.state.modal}
          items={this.state.items}
          handleModalFalse={this.handleModalFalse}
          currentIndex={this.state.currentIndex}
          featured={this.state.featured}
        />
        <RenderGallery
          items={this.state.items}
          responsive={this.responsive}
          onSlideChanged={this.onSlideChanged}
          currentIndex={this.state.currentIndex}
        />
        <button onClick={() => this.handleEnlargeClick()}>
          click to enlarge
        </button>
        <RenderThumbs
          items={this.state.items}
          slideNext={this.slideNext}
          slidePrev={this.slidePrev}
          slideTo={this.slideTo}
          responsive={this.responsive}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
*******
```

You can see the full Carousel implementation and `bug` in action here on this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2zwym3oqpy). Please feel free to fork it.

Right now my Modal only either shows the first image or all of them...

*I understand why I currently only get either the first or all of the images*, I just can't figure a solution for my issue.

**How can I make the featured image on the Modal to be the same as the one currently on the carousel**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is that your modal is looping over *all* of the items, and displaying them when you click the "enlarge" button. To fix this, you just need to use the `selectedIndex` with your `items` variable to get the currently selected `item`.

Sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/21p19wmpyy

Modal Code:

```
const Modal = ({ modal, items, handleModalFalse, currentIndex, featured }) => {
  return (
    <div className={modal ? "modal" : "hide"} onClick={handleModalFalse}>
      {/* this only features the first image */}
      {/* <img src={featured} /> */}
      {/* shows every image on modal*/}
      <div className="wrapper">
        <img src={items[currentIndex]} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much Hybrid! I was close but not close enough. I really appreciate your insight.